# ssh asks for password due to unable to locate file

Tags: ssh

I've been messing around with my SSH keys, and now I'm trying to get it to work. I've moved over the .pub and the SSH files that I use for connecting to the server which are called `saleslist`.

Now I've moved them over to `~/.ssh/` and both the pub and the normal one is there.

However when I try to SSH into my server I get asked for the password, even on the deploy account which I registered  with `--disabled-password`.

I ran `ssh -v sebastian@ip` and it returned:

```
debug1: Found key in /Users/Sebastian/.ssh/known_hosts:43
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Sebastian/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Sebastian/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Sebastian/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Sebastian/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Sebastian/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: any of those keys are included (public part) in `~sebastian/.ssh/authorized_keys` on ip hosts ? sshd is configured to accept keys ?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the public key is uploaded and available on the remote host in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Besides, ensure that the permissions on the `~/.ssh` directory are 700 (drwx------) and 600 (-rw-------) on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.